# How can I pass the product list from stripe and update the check out screen?

Tags: axios, stripe-payments

I have been working on this for a while and have run into different issues at different steps but currently I am wanting to populate the list of products hosted on stripes product page and then check out with the items on the page.

This is the current back end in node that populates the product list in the console.

```
`app.use(cors())
app.listen (4000)
{console.log ('server is runing on port 4000 bruh')};
app.use(express.static('public'));
const SECRET_KEY = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY; 
const URL = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/products';
axios.get(URL, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${SECRET_KEY}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',

'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS',

'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Api-Key, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    }
})
.then(response => { 
  //  here i console log the data 
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log ("product list is being sent from port 4000")
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);`
```

Here is the front end where am I trying to reach the back end server

```
`import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState(null);

  const URL = "http://localhost:4000";

  const Stripe_Public_Key = process.env.Stripe_Public_Key; // It's better to store secret keys in environment variables.

    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(URL, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${Stripe_Public_Key}`,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',

                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
        })      
      .then((response) => {
        setProducts(response.data);
        console.log (response.data)
      });
    }, []);
  
    if (!products) return null;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{products.name}</h1>
      <p>{products.price}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
`
```

The current error I am receiving is "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
any guidance is appreciated.